# How to use Meteor Upsert

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Having a bit of trouble getting my Meteor upsert function working. I am fairly (200 lines of code) new, and I'm having a bit of trouble.

The collection keeps on having additional rows inserted, rather than just updating. I spend the past 30 minutes googling, but I can't find any examples I can understand.

Here's my code:

```js
Values.upsert(
    {
      // Selector
      source: "SourceOne",
      currency: "USD"
    },
    {
      // Modifier
      value: res.data['data']['last']['value'],
      time: Date.now(),
    }
  );
```

I've also tried

```js
if(Values.find(
      {},{fields: {'source':"SourceOne", 'currency': "USD"}}
    )) {
    Values.update(
      {
        source: "SourceOne", 
        currency: "USD"
      },
      {
        value: res.data['data']['last']['value'],
        time: Date.now()
      }
    );
  } else {
    console.log('blah');
    Values.insert({
      source: "SourceOne", 
      currency: "USD",
      value: res.data['data']['last']['value'],
      time: Date.now()
    });
  }
```

And still can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Figured it out through trial and error... posted solution above

Comment: You should always post answer material as answers in the boxes below.

Comment: @MikeGraf I wasn't able to when I first joined Stack since I didn't have enough reputation to post answers or something. I've done so now

Answer (score 53):

Figured it out through trial and error:

```
Values.upsert({
    // Selector
    source: "SourceOne",
    currency: "USD"
}, {
    // Modifier
    $set: {
        value: res.data['data']['last']['value'],
        time: Date.now() // no comma needed here
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for the `// Selector` and `// Modifier` comments. Until I saw those I didn't really understand the concepts here...

Comment: Thanks for this! Sure wish the official documentation gave examples.

Comment: will it also insert `source` and `currency`when there is no document to update?

Comment: what happens when you use `$inc` instead of `$set`, does it use default value or default value +1 ?

Answer (score 13):

The above doesn't work for IDs. This works for me (with the same syntax as update):

```
Values.upsert(id,
{
  // Modifier
  $set: {
      value: res.data['data']['last']['value'],
      time: Date.now() // no need coma here
  }
}
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
values.update({"id":id},
       { $set: {
          value: res.data['data']['last']['value'],
          time: Date.now() // no need coma here
      } },
      { upsert: true }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Mongo.Collection#upsert(selector, modifier, [options], [callback])**
>
> ARGUMENTS
>
> selector: Mongo Selector, Object ID, or String Specifies which
> documents to modify
>
> modifier: Mongo Modifier Specifies how to modify the documents
>
> callback: Function Optional. If present, called with an error object as
> the first argument and, if no error, the number of affected documents
> as the second.
>
> OPTIONS: multi Boolean True to modify all matching documents; false to
> only modify one of the matching documents (the default).

https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-upsert