# If record exist, update if not create new

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
{
  "_id": "W4ZZxraDXGj3FtJek",
  "name": "Rust",
  "description": "new programming language by google",
  "organization": "rYefzmKDCoqKJQmeA",
  "status": "active",
  "dateAdded": "2018-02-07T13:51:31.564Z",
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "6BuSTu6GZybkmozWW",
      "role": "manager",
      "hours": "",
      "dateAdded": "2018-02-07T15:13:30.654Z",
      "reports": [
        {
          "date": "2018-02-06T12:39:32.118Z",
          "hours": "19123"
        },
        {
          "date": "2018-02-05T12:39:32.118Z",
          "hours": "19123"
        }
      ]
    },
{
      "id": "aFJlejSTu6erawlkjeru",
      "role": "manager",
      "hours": "",
      "dateAdded": "2018-02-07T15:13:30.654Z",
      "reports": [
        {
          "date": "2018-02-06T12:39:32.118Z",
          "hours": "19123"
        }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a collection like this. What I want to do is search a project by ID, search a single member and find a specific report based on date property. If it is found, I want to update the hours. If it’s not, I want to create a new report object.

I’m creating a test app to learn meteor. Currently new to meteor and NoSQLs (mongoDB)

```
 Projects.update({
       _id: projId,
       "members.id": memberId
    }, { 
       $set: { "members.$.hours": hours } 
      });
```

What I've done so far is update the 'hours' field but I added a new 'reports' field that has a nested objects.

Comment: Take a look at the `upsert` function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555473/how-to-use-meteor-upsert

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB has a concept of upsert and is set within the options within the update function:

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
   }
)
```

You'll most likely find the `$setOnInsert` operator for your case, as by default it only sets the update values that you've specified, if you want to insert other items on the insert but not the update you can use this operator. More information can be found here -https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/

See more reading - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option

Comment: What I did while waiting for answers is run a query, check if it returns a record (true, false) then do what i want. I'll definitely take a look a this.

Comment: This will be much better as the operation is atomic

Answer (score 1):

You can go simple route..
Use findOne to get record.

```
const p = Projects.findOne({_id:id});

//If record exists update or insert.

if(p){
Projects.update({_id:id},{$set:{abcd:defg}});
}else{
Projects.insert({abcd:defg});
}
```

Have control at each step. findOne query is very efficient.

Comment: This could result in concurrency issues

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did

Comment: What does 'concurrency issue' means @KevinSmith ?

Comment: If 2 requests/processes request that item and both receive it's not there, then they'll both insert and one will fail... and in this example, you've not specified a `_id` so 2 documents will be created instead of one.